# Second calling of an method with iterator throws ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, iterator

What I try to do - call twice the a method on two different List

:

- Element P must be removed if isTranslation() is true.
- Element P and the following element must be removed if the isTitle() is true;

I'm running the following code:

```
private List<P> nlPars; //initialised in constructor
private List<P> enPars; //initialised in constructor

public void build(){
...
  removeHeaders(nlPars); //first time calling, no problem
  removeHeaders(enPars); //second time calling, throws ConcurrentModificationException
...
}
```

calling this method:

```
    @VisibleForTesting
    void removeHeaders(final List<P> pars) {
        pars.removeIf(p -> isTranslation(p));

        for (final ListIterator<P> it = pars.listIterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            if (isTitle(it.next())) {
                it.remove();
                if (it.hasNext()) {
                    it.next();
                    it.remove();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

I have no idea why. The debugger tells me that on the second time, the pars.listIterator() cannot be evaluated/throws ConcurrentModificationException.

I've been looking for hours now to fix this. Maybe someone can help!

Regards,

Bart

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, the problem was not here. The problem was in the construction of enPars en nlPars. They were derived like `nlPars = pars.subList(...)`. That's fine, but they are views on the pars list and the iterator is the same, hence the problem.

Changing it solved the issue:

```
enPars = new ArrayList<P>(pars.subList(0, i));
```